# What are the most promising contenders for a theory of everything/unified theory besides string theory?

Tags: grand-unification

Many of us are debating this question on youtube and twitter. Has string theory really failed? What are the conditions under which string theory could be validated or rejected/falsified?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Welcome to the stack exchange.  Your title asks a completely different question from the body of your question.  Which are you asking?  I'd suggest that you not say "both" because they really are different.

Comment: I would look at anything to do with the inverse square law. I'm sure promising contenders will include or agree with it.

Answer (score 1):

String theory has stalled because there are many thousands of possible string theories .  Experiments in accelerators  and cosmological observations are needed to pick a specific one.

[See here](https://www.dummies.com/article/academics-the-arts/science/physics/string-theory-and-supersymmetry-178720/)

> According to string theory, all particles in the universe can be divided into two types: bosons and fermions. String theory predicts that a type of connection, called supersymmetry, exists between these two particle types.

> Under supersymmetry, a fermion must exist for every boson and a boson for every fermion. Unfortunately, experiments have not yet detected these extra particles.

ending with:

> Scientists hope that astronomical observations or experiments with particle accelerators will uncover some of these higher-energy [supersymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superstring_theory) particles, providing support for this prediction of string theory.

The search for super-symmetric particles is one of the main aims of [high energy experiments.](https://www.home.cern/science/physics/supersymmetry) [Here is a list](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/CMSPublic/PhysicsResultsSUS#Run_2_Results_13_TeV) for one experiment.